# How to insert an image into a cell in office 365 Excel?

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office

I want to insert image inside cell with not movable. Otherwise add an Image in comments also fine. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a comment, which looks like you have above, first add a comment, and follow these steps:

1. Right-click the cell which contains the comment.
2. Choose Show/Hide Comments, and clear any text from the comment.
3. Click on the border of the comment, to select it & Right Click on the border.
4. Choose Format Comment. On the Colors and Lines tab, click the drop-down arrow for Color.
5. Click Fill Effects at the bottom. On the picture tab, click Select Picture
6. Locate and select the picture. To keep the picture in proportion, add a check mark to
   Lock Picture Aspect Ratio
7. Click Insert, click OK, click OK
8. Go back to the cell, right click and click Hide Comment.

Now when you mouse over that cell, the picture will come up.

If you want the picture to permanantly be in the cell, use the Insert tab-Pictures.  Once inserted into your cell, right click on the picture, go to Size and Properties, and click the Move and size with cells under the Properties.

Comment: But these options are available in "Note". Not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since the options provided by Kent are not available in Excel 365 you can use the following VBA code to add an image in a specific cell as note.

```
Sub addPicture()
    With ActiveCell
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture("C:\Users\User\Desktop\YourImageHere.jpg")
            With .Comment.Shape
                .Height = 100 'adjust Height
                .Width = 200 'adjust Width
            End With
    End With
End Sub
```